Registrar respuestas
Tengo este codigo en el cual genero unas preguntas y lo que quiero es guardar las respuestas de cada pregunta, pero no las guarda, aqui les dejo mi codigo donde deberia de registrar mis preguntas en la tabla checklist_answers, ya me muestra las preguntas en el index y las tengo dentro de un formulario, lo que quiero es que registre las respuestas normal, pero al seleccionar la opcion no cumple,me muestra otras opciones para responder, lo que quiero es que no sean necesario rellenar esas respuestas al realizar el checklist,solo si es necesario.
De ante mano muchas gracias, saludos!!
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GuardarChecklist(ChecklistViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase[] evidencias)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Iterar sobre las preguntas y guardar las respuestas
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Questions.Count; i++)
            {
                var pregunta = model.Questions[i];
                string respuesta = Request.Form["Respuestas[" + i + "]"]; // Obtener respuesta específica
                string observacion = Request.Form["Observaciones[" + i + "]"]; // Obtener observación específica
                string responsable = Request.Form["Responsables[" + i + "]"]; // Obtener responsable específico

                // Obtener la evidencia asociada a esta pregunta
                HttpPostedFileBase evidencia = evidencias[i];

                SaveAnswer(model.ChecklistId, pregunta.IdQuestion, respuesta, observacion, evidencia, responsable);
            }

            // Redirigir a la acción deseada después de guardar
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // Si el modelo no es válido, manejar el error de validación
        return View("Index", model);
    }





    // Método para guardar la respuesta en la base de datos
    private void SaveAnswer(int checklistId, int questionId, string respuesta, string observacion, HttpPostedFileBase evidencia, string responsable)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena))
        {
            string query = @"
                INSERT INTO checklist_answers (ChecklistId, QuestionId, Respuesta, Observacion, EvidenciaPath, Responsable)
                VALUES (@ChecklistId, @QuestionId, @Respuesta, @Observacion, @EvidenciaPath, @Responsable)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChecklistId", checklistId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionId", questionId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Respuesta", respuesta);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observacion", observacion);

            if (evidencia != null && evidencia.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Evidencias/"), Path.GetFileName(evidencia.FileName));
                evidencia.SaveAs(path);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvidenciaPath", path);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvidenciaPath", DBNull.Value);
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Responsable", responsable);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

Y aqui les dejo donde se muestran las preguntas (Index.cshtml)
@model LPA.Models.ChecklistViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Checklist";
}

<div class="container form-control">
    <h2>Checklist</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GuardarChecklist", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChecklistId)

        if (Model.Questions != null && Model.Questions.Any())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
            {
                var question = Model.Questions[i];
                <div class="question-group">
                    <label>@question.Question</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="Respuestas[@i]" class="respuesta-select form-control form-select" required>
                            <option value="">Seleccione una respuesta</option>
                            <option value="si">Sí cumple</option>
                            <option value="no">No cumple</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-lg-end">
                        <div class="form-group observacion-evidencia" style="display: none;">
                            <label>Observación</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Observaciones[@i]" class="form-control observacion-input" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group observacion-evidencia" style="display: none;">
                            <label>Evidencia</label>
                            <input type="file" name="evidencias[@i]" class="form-control evidencia-input" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Responsable</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Responsables[@i]" value="@question.responsable" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    }
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.respuesta-select').forEach(function (select) {
        select.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var questionGroup = this.closest('.question-group');
            var observacionEvidenciaGroups = questionGroup.querySelectorAll('.observacion-evidencia');
            if (this.value === 'no') {
                observacionEvidenciaGroups.forEach(function (group) {
                    group.style.display = 'block';
                    group.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function (input) {
                        input.required = true;
                    });
                });
            } else {
                observacionEvidenciaGroups.forEach(function (group) {
                    group.style.display = 'none';
                    group.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function (input) {
                        input.required = false;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .question-group {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .observacion-evidencia {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>

